# Tagged Facebook photos (Photos of you) in Windows 8 Photos app

Tags: windows-8, facebook, windows-photo-gallery

Windows 8 Photos app seems to sync only the Albums that I own in my Facebook profile leaving the tagged photos aside.

I have a lot of my photos being tagged by my facebook friends. The app doesn't seem to sync them, Since I don't own them.

As of now, AFAIK, there is no default app option to get the tagged photos. Does anyone have any tweak?

Comment: I would simply use a different application.

Comment: @Ramhound But by then the concept of being synchronised would be missing.

Comment: @Ramhound If you're not going to post a solution or at least research, don't post.